# Simulate HTTP get request in hping

Tags: packet-injection

I need to simulate HTTP request in hping.

Can anyone please suggest how this can be done?

Just specifying port as 80 will suffice?

Answer (score 0):

With [hping](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hping3) is impossible because with hping is not working on the application layer and HTTP is in application layer.

> hping3 is a network tool able to send custom TCP/IP packets and to
>   display target replies like ping program does with ICMP replies.
>   hping3 handle fragmentation, arbitrary packets body and size and can
>   be used in order to transfer files encapsulated under supported
>   protocols.

If you want simulate HTTP request could use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).